# Biblatex: override title for specific bib entry exported from Citavi

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to cite a law but it has a very long title.
The thing I want to achieve is displaying the short title (e.g. "BDSG") in my footnote and the long title ("Bundesdatenschutzgesetz") in my bibliography.

I'm using Citavi for organizing my sources.
That's why I can't override the .bib entry manually, it will be overwritten every time I start a Citavi export.

This is a code sample:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,dashed=false,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\bibliography{BIBFILE}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum\cite{BDSG}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Cite in text should be "BDSG" and the name of the source in my bibliography "Bundesdatenschutzgesetz [MORE INFORMATION]".

Do you have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can make your question easier to answer if you give a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that we can copy and compile directly. You are more than halfway there but missing the document class and the relevant `.bib` entry.

Comment: I guess you want `shorttitle = {BDSG},` or `shorthand = {BDSG},` (the second will substitute the whole citation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `shorttitle` or `shorthand` field. So ideally things should be as easy as

```
@online{bdsg,
  title      = {Bundesdatenschutzgesetz},
  shorttitle = {BDSG},
}
```

If you, however, can't modify the `.bib` file, you can let Biber do it for you. The following adds `shorttitle = {BDSG},` to the entry with the key `bdsg`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@online{bdsg,
  title = {Bundesdatenschutzgesetz},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,dashed=false,style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{\A bdsg \Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shorttitle, fieldvalue=BDSG]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\cite{bdsg}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Johannes Good. But really the solution is to use a citation manager that lets you export `shorttitle` or `shorthand` fields as well.

Comment: @Johannes Please check the edited answer. There was a massive bug in the earlier version.

Comment: What was the issue before adding "match=\regexp{\A bdsg \Z}, final"?

Comment: @Johannes Without the `final` every entry got the `BDSG` which is obviously not right. `\regexp{\A bdsg \Z}` makes sure we really only match `bdsg` and not, say `abdsgy`

Comment: citavi lets you export `shorthand` and `shorttitle`, you just have to map the fields to each other correctly. For that, refer to citavi documentation of your version. btw, in citavi 6 beta 8, `AuthorsAbbreaviation` cannot have any export value (e.g. `shortauthor`). This is a known issue and the developers said they would fix it with the next beta version or final release.